# Computation of the derived series $S_3$ and show that it is solvable

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Let $S_3$ be the symmetric group on 3 elements, i.e., the group of bijections from $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself. Let $\sigma \in S_3$ such that $\sigma(1) = 2, \sigma(2) = 3, \sigma(3) = 1$.

I have already shown the following points:

- $|S_3| = 6$
- $\langle \sigma \rangle $ is normal in $S_3$

From shown results in the lecture I know that

$S_3/\langle \sigma \rangle $ is abelian $\implies [S_3,S_3] \subseteq \langle \sigma \rangle$. Further I know that $S_3$ is not abelian and $[S_3, S_3]$ is normal in $S_3$.

How can I conclude that $[S_3, S_3] = \langle \sigma \rangle$?

My thought:

$${\rm card}(S_3) = {\rm card}([S_3,S_3]) \cdot {\rm card}(S_3/[S_3,S_3])$$

or more precisely

$$6 ={\rm card}([S_3,S_3]) \cdot{\rm card}(S_3/[S_3,S_3])$$

but since $[S_3,S_3] \subseteq \langle \sigma \rangle$ we have that ${\rm card}([S_3,S_3]) \leq{\rm card}(\langle \sigma \rangle)$ and since $[S_3,S_3]$ is not trivial its cardinality can not be $1$. So it is either $2$ or $3$.

How can I proceed from here on?

Comment: Yes, $[S_3,S_3]=A_3\cong C_3$ is abelian of order $3$. So $S_3^{(1)}=[S_3,S_3]$ is abelian, and we have that $S_3$ is solvable by definition (the derived series ends with $1$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde But why is $[S_3, S_3]$ necessarily equal to $\langle \sigma \rangle$ and cannot be another normal subgroup besides $\langle \sigma \rangle$?

Comment: Because it must be $A_3$, see the duplicate. In general, $[S_n,S_n]=A_n$, the alternating group. And $A_3$ is cyclic, generated by $(123)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is there a way to argue that $[S_3, S_3] = \langle \sigma \rangle$ without considering the alternating group and just with the given informations?

Comment: Of course you can argue without saying $A_3$, but nevertheless $\langle\sigma \rangle$ *is* just $A_3$. So the argument from the duplicate still applies. Just call it $\langle\sigma \rangle$, and not $A_3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have now a different approach. One can show that $[S_3, S_3] < \langle \sigma \rangle$ (subgroup). Then by Lagrange Theorem the cardinality of $[S_3, S_3]$ must divide the cardinality of $\langle \sigma \rangle$ so the cardinality of $[S_3, S_3]$ can be either $1$ or $3$. But $1$ is not possible since it is not trivial. So cardinality is $3$ and since it is a subset of a set with cardinality $3$ as well it has to be equal to that set $\implies [S_3, S_3] = \langle \sigma \rangle$.